# jquery ajax post request does not accept absolute url rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running a rails application and i have a jquery ajax post request

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/ags/request/',
        method : 'POST',
        data: paramsData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {},
  })
```

Someone in my request when this is called, i am expect a post call to be made to the url since it is a different application but instead the call that is made is from my current application and it treats the external url as a relative url so this is what is called

`http:localhost:3000/listings/http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/ags/request/`

Not sure why it is treating my external url as a relative url. Anyone with any solutions most welcome.

Comment: Do you have `$.ajaxSetup()` anywhere in the code to set up a global config?

Comment: Also are you sure it is not `url: '/http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/ags/request/',` ? Otherwise the code should work.. I am not seeing what could be wrong

Comment: it is definitely not /http in the code and i dont have ajaxSetup anywhere in the code @ArupRakshit

Answer (score 1):

If it's exactly as shown in your question:
`'http:127.0.0.1:8000/api/ags/request/`, then that's invalid syntax. The protocol segment of your URL needs to start `http://`. I.e.:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ags/request`

Ultimately you won't want this hardcoded anyway once you deploy to a production server.